# Feetching all adunits relate to one line item

Tags: google-dfp

Is there any optimal way of fetching all adunits related to one line item?

At the moment our solution takes the adunits from the line item and expands them in a breadth-first search which is not really optimal since we end up doing many API calls (not many per second per the total time is pretty long). This is done by running a PQL statement which fetches all the adunits with parent id withing the current set (last level of the tree).

One solution we are not doing at the moment and we plan on implementing is caching the results after traversing the adunit tree but that would nto solve the long time it takes for us to actually find all the adunits for one campaign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No methods simplifying this available in DFP API. 
But the following algorithm could be more efficient than BFS if you have many line items:

- select *all* ad units with `hasChildren = false`
- use `parentPath` of the extracted ad units to fully reconstruct the ad units tree & cache it somewhere
- once you need to find the entire tree of a line item targets use this structure

Comment: From both API docs and testing around, I am sure you can not select based on hasChildren so the method will always result in returning all adunits which might be a little too much sicne we're talking about 100 000

Comment: gave you a +1 for an interesting approach that might help others tho

Comment: You can filter by hasChildren in at least python API because this is a separate ad unit attribute. You can easily check it here - https://dfp-playground.appspot.com/, just enter i.e WHERE hasChildren = 1 in adunit service

Comment: interesting. Before when i asked hasChildren = true or false it would have listed all and not only false. All APIs are built on top of the SOAP service so this is not language related. Even as such I have the problem of too many ad units but at least you gave me some good ideas and points.

Comment: also with point out that in the official API docs filtering by hasChildren is not listed.
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201708/InventoryService#getAdUnitsByStatement

Comment: After more indepth tests I want to bring to your knowledge that hasChildren false also returns elements for which hasChildren is true ... while hasChildren true returns correctly but not all

Comment: Can you reproduce it via https://dfp-playground.appspot.com/? It sounds odd, more so because DFP API folks recommend using this attribute in the queries i.e in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/How$20to$20get$20first$20hierarchy$20AdUnits$20in$20InventoryService$20for$20a$20given$20client%7Csort:date/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/OutYD9Wf0kQ/zY1rCSp_AQAJ